# How to iterate each row and find the next matching column value from a specific column from one dataframe and comparing it to another dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, iteration, comparison

I have two dataframes:

DF1: Group A

```
employee_id  |     key
100               101001
101               020208
102               101002
103               020208
104               020208
...               ...
300               010506
```

DF2: Group B

```
employee_id  |    key
110              101001
111              020208
112              020105
113              020208
114              020208
...              ...
600              051007
```

Compare the `key` from each row in both dataframes. With each matched employee, create a new dataframe with `DF1.employee_id, DF1.key, DF2.employee_id`  and remove the matched person from DF2.

I want to iterate each employee in DF1 at a time and find a marched record in DF2 and once had a match remove that record in DF2. Thee goal is not to have duplicated matched employee from DF2 for each matched employee from DF1. How to iterate this process?

```
clean = df_1.merge(df_2, on=['key'], how='left')
```

This above script will give me duplicated records. I want the new dataframe to look like this:

New Dataframe (Sample):

```
employee_id_df1  |    key      |  employee_id_df2
100                  101001         110
101                  020208         111
103                  020208         113
104                  020208         114
```

The goal is to have 1-to-1 match.

Comment: Is the column `key` the same in `df1` and `df2`?

Comment: @AndrejKesely its different

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a temporary column that you use in the merge:

```py
df1["tmp"] = df1.groupby("key").cumcount()
df2["tmp"] = df2.groupby("key").cumcount()

df_out = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=["key", "tmp"], how="inner")
df_out = df_out.rename(
    columns={"employee_id_x": "employee_id_df1", "employee_id_y": "employee_id_df2"}
).drop(columns="tmp")

print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
   employee_id_df1     key  employee_id_df2
0              100  101001              110
1              101   20208              111
2              102   20105              112
3              103   20208              113
4              104   20208              114
```